# Laravel 5 filesystem: add FTP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, flysystem

Its very simple:

How i can use FTP driver with Laravel 5 filesystem?

Only available s3, rackspace and local. Im trying to use manual from official docs but its not work!
Please, if you know how to use FTP driver for create new Filesystem disk - tell me step by step.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install composer package "league/flysystem-sftp": "~1.0" as described in https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Flysystem

Tips for getting started with sftp can be found from https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-sftp

Comment: but laravel official docs says about integrated filesysem:  
  
«You can create a custom driver if you want to use one of these additional adapters in your Laravel application. Don't worry, it's not too hard!»
  
But for me its really hard, need just FTP